# List.js not working when using an ampersand (&) in value

Tags: javascript, jquery, list.js

When using an ampersand, either explicitly as `&` or using HTML character codes as `&amp;`, [List.js](https://listjs.com/) breaks. Here's the code, working for the first filter, but not for the second:

```js
$(function() {

  var options = {
    valueNames: ["name", "category"]
  };

  var userList = new List("search-results", options);
  var activeFilters = [];

  // filter
  $(".filter").change(function() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    var value = $(this).data("value");

    if (isChecked) {
      // add to list of active filters
      activeFilters.push(value);
    } else {
      // remove from active filters
      activeFilters.splice(activeFilters.indexOf(value), 1);
    }
    userList.filter(function(item) {
      if (activeFilters.length > 0) {
        return activeFilters.indexOf(item.values().category) > -1;
      }
      return true;
    });
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monaco;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

ul span {
  margin-left: 4px
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0
}

.list {
  padding: 10px;
  background: steelblue;
}

.package {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: pink;
}

.package .text {
  display: block;
}

.package .category {
  background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.0/list.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="checkbox-btn">
    <label>
      <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="history" data-value="History" /><span>History</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="checkbox-btn">
    <label>
      <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="arts & crafts" data-value="Arts & Crafts" /><span>Arts & Crafts</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="results-container">
  <div id="search-results">
    <div class="list">

      <div class="package">
        <span class="text">Placeholder Text</span>
        <span class="category">History</span>
      </div>
      
      <div class="package">
        <span class="text">Placeholder Text</span>
        <span class="category">Arts & Crafts</span>
      </div>

      <div class="package">
        <span class="text">Placeholder Text</span>
        <span class="category">History</span>
      </div>
      
      <div class="package">
        <span class="text">Placeholder Text</span>
        <span class="category">Arts & Crafts</span>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to allow an ampersand as the filtered category name? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser replaces `&` for `&amp;`, so you need to replace back on the filter function:

```
return activeFilters.indexOf(item.values().category.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")) > -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with the way List.js is implemented: Searching through [list.js source on GitHub](https://github.com/javve/list.js/blob/master/dist/list.js) one finds lots of references to element `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` properties, but *no references* to `textContent` or `innerHTML` properties.

Logging the `item` argument passed to the `userList.filter` function, `item._values` appears as

```
 _values: Object { name: "", category: "Arts &amp; Crafts" }
```

so clearly `list.js` is using HTML content to implement filtering, and getting (or calculating) `Arts &amp; Crafts` as the HTML content it is looking for in `category` class elements being used to filter the list.

A solution predicted to solve the problem works in practice: when processing filter button input changes, convert the text held in the `data-value` attribute to the "text/hmtl" format that `list.js` is using (instead of leaving it as "text/plain") before pushing it into the `activeFilters` array:

```
  // filter
  $(".filter").change(function() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    var value = $(this).data("value");
    value = value.replace("&", "&amp;");  // filter value as "text/html" 

    if (isChecked) {
      // add to list of active filters
      activeFilters.push(value);
    } else {
      // remove from active filters
      activeFilters.splice(activeFilters.indexOf(value), 1);
    }
    userList.filter(function(item) {
      if (activeFilters.length > 0) {
        return activeFilters.indexOf(item.values().category) > -1;
      }
      return true;
    });
  });
```